# Cassandra: Data loss after adding new node

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

We had a two nodes cassandra cluster which we want to expand to four.
We followed the procedure described there: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html

But after adding two more nodes (at same time, with a 2 minutes interval as recommended in the documentation), we experienced some data loss. In some column families, there was missing elements.

Here is the `nodetool netstats`:

```
[centos@ip-10-11-11-187 ~]$ nodetool status
Datacenter: us-west-2
=====================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.11.11.187  5.63 MB    256     ?       0e596912-d649-4eed-82a4-df800c422634  2c
UN  10.11.1.104   748.79 MB  256     ?       d8b96739-0858-4926-9eb2-27c96ca0a1c4  2c
UN  10.11.11.24   7.11 MB    256     ?       e3e76dcf-2c39-42e5-a34e-9e986d4a9f7c  2c
UN  10.11.1.231   878.91 MB  256     ?       cc1b5cfd-c9d0-4ca9-bbb1-bce4b2deffc1  2c

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless
```

I don't quite understand if the "Note" is bad or not.

When we added the nodes, we put the two first servers - already available in the cluster - in the seeds of the configuration of the first added node. For the second added node, we put the newly added node in the seeds as well.

We are using `EC2Snitch`, and the `listen_address` has been set to the above addresses on each server.

We didn't run the cleanup yet, but we tried to run a repair, and there was written that nothing were to be repaired in our keycap.

Here is how our cluster was created:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE keyspace_name WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'us-west-2': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

And the options of all of our tables:

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace_name."CFName" (
    // ...
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

The data reappears if I decommission the new nodes.

**EDIT: It was actually an error when reading the documentation... A colleague did set auto_bootstrap to false instead of setting it to true...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should perform `nodetool rebuild` on the new nodes after you add them with auto_bootstrap: false

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsRebuild.html

HTH

Comment: Cool, I didn't know this option. I finally decommissioned the node from the cluster and then added it back and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can specify the keyspace name to remove the Node which in this case is

```
nodetool status keyspace_name
```